# open html document with excel save as xls with batch file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, batch, vba, macros

I would like to run a batch file that will open an html file with excel and subsequently save the opened html file as a xls or xlsx document.  Ideally, the batch would then be scheduled to run nightly. Using a simple code like the one below will open an html document in excel

```
start excel test.html
```

Where I am stuck is where to go next with the code. Would anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question:

The solution to this problem is tackled by writing two scripts:  first is a vba script written in excel and saved to an xlsm document.  The second is a .bat file which will run the previously mentioned xlsm document to trigger the vba script which ultimately will convert the html document to xlsx.

1st:  In Excel there are two things to do create the VBA code that will save the html document as an xlsx document (Let's Call this A).  The second step is to create VBA code that will automatically run the previously mentioned code [designated to save the htlm as an excel file and then close](Let's call this B).

The code for A is

```
Sub Open_HTML_Save_XLSX()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="**NameOfHTMLfileHere.HTML"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "**NewName.XLSX", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

You'll notice the code is very simple.  To summarize the code says, open html document, save as xlsx document, close work book. The code for A goes into the section for modules.

For Part B you'll have to save another VBA script within the 'ThisWorkbook' section of the Microsoft Excel Objects folder for the xlsm document.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call Open_HTML_Save_XLSX
   Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Again, not that complicated.  The script just says when you open this work book run the VBA script that will do the file conversion and then quit out of excel.

So, once the XLSM document is set up the only thing left to do is write a batch script to open the XLSM document which will do all the work.

The batch is super simple:

```
echo on
start excel "vbatest.xlsm"
```

Running the batch, opens the xlsm document.  Opening the Xlsm document triggers VBA code to run.  The VBA code then opens the desired html document and saves it as xlsx.  Excel then closes, the batch file has run its course and your objective has been met.

That's all folks, thanks for all the fish.